# C# Elmah - how to fix when it is working in one website but not another on the same server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, elmah

I have two copies of the same website on my IIS7.5 windows 2008 server:

```
Default Website/my_app
Beta/my_app
```

The code base for the two are identical, and they both have identical web.config files.

On the default website, ELMAH works and logs messages (to file), but on the Beta website it does not log anything.  What can I check to see why it is not working?

I have compared the ACLs for both physical folders and they are the same.

Comment: A good sub question is - what ACLs are required to allow ELMAH to write the errors to file.  I have 4 identical copies that do not have this ELMAH problem (works on the dev, staging, live, and live failover sites), it just doesn't work on the brand new beta site.

Comment: All it need is a write permission for apppool identity. We are using very simple webdeploy package for automagic managing ACLs. You should check ACLs for apppools I'm sure your site use different identities.

Comment: @Sergey Thanks - the new app pool had "ApplicationPoolIdentity" as it's identity.  As soon as I changed it to Network Service ELMAH started logging again.  If you want to change your comment to an answer, I will upvote and accept.

Comment: @JK nice to hear. done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it need is a *write* permission for apppool identity.
We are using very simple webdeploy package for automagic managing ACLs.
You should check ACLs for appPools
I'm **sure** your site use different identities.